# Is it possible de deploy an HashiCorp Vault already configured on the client side?

Tags: java, hashicorp-vault

this is my use case. I have a lecagy java application and this application needs some secrets to performs some tasks. This java application is shipped to the client as an executable jar and can't not connect over internet.

I am wondering it could be possible de deploy also a HashiCorp Vault already configured (initialised...)with those secrets. That's means configure the vault, add secrets, generate ssl certificates and then ship this to the client aside this java application so that secrets will not be visible.

Comment: Is the goal to stop the client from reading the secrets? The secrets that are encoded in the Vault configuration/image/whatnot that you are sending them? The secrets that your application needs access to that you also send them in binary form? If so, any attempts to do this are bound to fail: you're sending them the secrets for them to use. You can't make it impossible for them to also read the secrets.

Comment: I want only the java application to read those secrets. But they need to be stored locally because the java application is not connected to internet

Comment: You probably can set up such an image. But there's no reliable way to stop a dedicated customer from reading the secrets from that image, if your Java application can read them. The simplest first approach is to just debug the Java application and step through when it reads the secrets.

Comment: In other words, your solution would be as insecure as storing the secrets in an encrypted file with the key or password in plain text next to it. Instead of taking 2 minutes to crack, it might take 5, but your solution is not worth the effort. +If your application cannot connect to anything, what does it need secrets for?